# Is "giddy" derived from "Gid" which was Middle English for "God"?

Tags: etymology, errors, middle-english

Recently I posted an answer about the etymology of *goodbye*, in that answer I included a reference that cited ***Gid be with you***, which was dated 1400-1499. The phrase was mentioned in *Diachronic Pragmatics: Seven case studies in English illocutionary development*, and written by [Dr. Leslie K. Arnovick](http://english.ubc.ca/persons/leslie-arnovick/)

Below I include a cropped screenshot showing the citation in table 6.1, on page 99.

[image]

Sceptical, and fascinated, I wanted to find out more. But try as I did, I could not find any *online* references that confirmed *Gid* (meaning God) was [Middle English](http://www.thehistoryofenglish.com/history_middle.html).

1. [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=god&allowed_in_frame=0) says

> **Old English** *god* "supreme being, deity; the Christian God; image of a god; godlike person," from Proto-Germanic *guthan (source also of Old Saxon, Old Frisian, Dutch *god*, Old High German *got*, German *Gott*, Old Norse *guð*, Gothic *guþ*), from PIE *ghut- "that which is invoked" (source also of Old Church Slavonic zovo "to call," Sanskrit *huta*- "invoked," an epithet of Indra), from root *gheu(e)- "to call, invoke."

2. Wikipedia's page for [God (word)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_(word)) basically repeats Etymonline but in greater detail.
3. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gid) informs that *gid* can refer to a sheep disease; an obsolete term for a fiddle; or Scots for *good*. For scrupulousness, I also checked the wiktionary entries for: Dutch *gód*, Swedish *göd*, Icelandic *goð* and Old High German *got*
4. Wiktionary also directed me to ***[guid](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=barNBj_XhV0C&pg=PA134&dq=guid%20good%20Chaucer&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim_oiMitjTAhWMChoKHdCwAMIQ6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=guid%20good%20Chaucer&f=false)***, which is cited in Chaucer's Canterbury Tales; however, it is an archaic spelling variant of *good*.
5. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gid) states that the sheep disease called *gid* is a back-formation of ***giddy***, and dates it from 1601.
6. Under the etymology of [***giddy***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/giddy), M-W says

> **Middle English** *gidy* mad, foolish, from Old English *gydig* possessed, mad; akin to Old English *god* god.

---

Questions

1. Is **Gid** Middle English for *God*?  Or is “Gid be with you” a misprint?
2. Did **giddy** originally mean to be possessed by God?

Comment: I doubt that "akin to Old English *god*" is meant to mean that **giddy** ever meant possessed by God (capital G, Christian god implied). Rather there would be an etymological connection between the word for a deity and the word for a possessing spirit.

Comment: Related: **1** [Origin of the similarity of “god” and “good”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341888/origin-of-the-similarity-of-god-and-good) **2** [Was “God be with ye” grammatically correct at the time?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196682/was-god-be-with-ye-grammatically-correct-at-the-time) **3** [How, or where, did “Ye God” become “egad”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12648/how-or-where-did-ye-god-become-egad) **4** [Where does the word “good” come from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196848/where-does-the-word-good-come-from)

Comment: Source: [**What is the origin of the word “goodbye”?**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/what-is-the-origin-of-the-word-goodbye)

Comment: FWIW, Fraser McAlpine [claims](https://www.bbcamerica.com/anglophenia/2014/05/frasers-phrases-oh-giddy-aunt) that *giddy* "is based on **gidi**, a word derived from **gudo**, the old Norse word for God". He doesn't cite any sources, and I didn't bother checking, but maybe the words he mentioned could provide some clues?

Answer (score 11):

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/78167?rskey=WsJ08D&result=2#eid) does place the etymology of "giddy" squarely as one possessed by a god.

> Old English *gidig* insane, is shown by its guttural initial to be a graphic variant of gydig < prehistoric gudīgo- , apparently < Old Germanic gudom **god** n. and >int. The primary sense thus appears to be ‘**possessed by a god**, ἔνθεος ’; compare Old English ylfig insane, lit. ‘elf-possessed’, similarly < ælf elf n.1

Early alternate spellings include "*gidie*," "*gidy*," and "*gidi*."

By 1556, "gid" was a term for a brain illness in sheep, likely related to the implication of insanity. A source cited at 1745 offers "giddiness" or "gid" as a term for this disease:

[image]

- *[Agriculture Improv'd: Or, The Practice of Husbandry Display'd](https://books.google.com/books?id=eikMAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA107&lpg=PA107&dq=The%20other%20Day%20you%20lost%20a%20Sheep%20by%20the%20Gid,%20or%20Giddiness.&source=bl&ots=aqFS0RkTA0&sig=J5uhsd8R7isZSyvWKd_ROl74wOU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3ybmBtNrTAhXilVQKHVcrBcgQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=The%20other%20Day%20you%20lost%20a%20Sheep%20by%20the%20Gid%2C%20or%20Giddiness.&f=false)* by William Ellis

> The other Day you lost a Sheep by the **Gid**, or **Giddiness**.

Nothing I could find in OED appeared to indicate that "Gid" was a precursor of "God," though it seems to have been an alternate spelling at some points in time.

**God**:

> Cognate with Old Frisian god, Old Dutch god (Middle Dutch, Dutch god), Old Saxon god (Middle Low German got, (inflected) gōd-, godd-)

---

According to [Bosworth-Toller Anglo-Saxon Dictionary](http://www.bosworthtoller.com/016986), "gid" or "gyd" meant a *poem, song, proverb,* or *riddle* earlier than the meaning related to sheep illness.

> *Gid oft wrecen* (a song oft sung) [recited], Beo. Th. 2135; B, 1065.